# Search plot by total area of two adjacent plots

Tags: qgis, area, expression

I've got some QGIS data where each plot is described with some attributes e.g.  `Shape_Area` which is the field describing the area of plot in `m2`. 
Normally I search for plot using the expression e.g. `Shape_Area >= 1000 AND Shape_Area <= 1100`, however this time I need to find two connected plots given their total area.

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Something like: take each 2-tuple of connected plots, add up their `Shape_Area`s and evaluate if the sum is within a range? How can the plots be connected?

Comment: I am quite new to spatial data and QGIS. How to connect plots? Let's say if they share one or two points together, then let's consider them adjacent. What would be the easiest solution?
Regarding the total area, yes, let's sum 2 values and use resulting value in the higher/less than condition.

Comment: _Join attributes by location (Summary)_ tool can create a table with the _sum_ operation of the _Shape_Area_ field, for the _touches_ predicate. But it assumes all the plots that touches each one. There must be some appropriate SQL query to return each pair of plots that are touched, but I don't know it. I hope that some specialists can offer their answers. Meanwhile I conduct my research on this. The question seems very good to me.

Answer (score 1):

**The Virtual Layer way**

- Assuming that you have a Polygon vector layer named *plots*.
- Assuming that each feature of the *plots* layer has *plotId* and *area* fields.

You can [create a Virtual Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?highlight=virtual%20layer#creating-virtual-layers) with one feature for each pair of geometries in the layer *plots* that are touched, with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    ST_Union( p1.geometry, p2.geometry) geometry, 
    p1.plotId plotId1, 
    p2.plotId plotId2, 
    ( p1.area + p2.area) sum_area 
FROM 
    plots p1, 
    plots p2 
WHERE 
    ST_Touches( p1.geometry, p2.geometry) 
    AND 
    p1.plotId < p2.plotId
```

The Output is a new Multipolygon virtual vector layer with **one** (see *DISCLAIMER* and *EDIT*) feature for each pair of plot geometries that touche, *plotId1* and *plotId2* fields, and *sum_area* field with the sum of the areas to search.

Note that when digitizing the test plots I had to enable the topological edition for the perimeter segments to be recognized by the `ST_Touches()` function, if your plots do not meet topological conditions you can try adding an `OR ST_Overlaps()` similar condition in the `WHERE` clause.

---

DISCLAIMER:

I am giving my first steps with SQL queries in PostGIS. I don't know how to select a single feature for each pair of plots. For example, if the geometries of *plotId* 5 and *plotId 6* are touching each other, there will be a feature in which `plotId1 = 5` and `plotId2 = 6`, but there will also be another feature in which `plotId1 = 6` and `plotId2 = 5`. Both features with the same sum of area and spatial equivalent geometries.

---

[@CyrilMikhalchenko'scomment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311619/search-plot-by-total-area-of-two-adjacent-plots/311701?noredirect=1#comment505846_311701) showed me how to avoid mirroring.